# Syntax error on token "super", invalid Name , super.ToString() compiler error

Tags: java

Can you please help me guys? I am having this problem for hours now, searched everywhere, nothing, i know this could be a duplicate, but nothing solved the issue. Calling the base class method simply doesn't work! What am I missing?

**Syntax error on token "super", invalid Name**

```
class Base
{
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "base";
    }
}
class SubClass extends Base
{
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return super().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code as text, not picture.

Comment: Remove the brackets from `super()`

Comment: The downvotes are real! Thank you, it worked. The inconsistency in Java is annoying.

Comment: @MihailGeorgescu What inconsistency? `super()` is a call, `super` is an object. The same as `this()` and `this`.

Comment: @MihailGeorgescu The downvotes are likely because you posted a blurry picture of code instead of just text. Always post code as text.

Comment: @Carcigenicate fixed it. It was awful indeed. I apolagise.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I am used to C#'s base keyword, it's just base in any case. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work due to curious Java syntax.

You use `super()` in a constructor, the parentheses are necessary to supply any parameters.

**Note** that in your case it is superfluous as the base class constructor will be called anyway.

But in the overloaded method, you use `super` without the parentheses. In this context the keyword stands in for the `this` pointer of the base class.

Answer (score -1):

it should be `super.toString();`not super().toString();

Comment: Please explain why. Answers telling to do something without understanding why are not that helpful.